# Drag&Drop сортировка столбцов таблицы

Tags: jquery, javascript

Возникла необходимость сортировки столбцов таблицы, причем способ Drag&Drop. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с готовыми решениями?

Comment: `draggable` и `[sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/)` в `jquery ui` смотрели?

Comment: Конечно. Но с его помощью можно максимум сортировать стобцы каждой строки, а не столбцы таблицы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот, что-то [набросал похожее на правду](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/fCq3d/2/). Нет времени углубляться, поэтому грязновато, хотя можно было бы и оригинальней способ придумать. Таких в бошке уже два созрело, но надо и своей работой позаниматься ))

Comment: До подобного костыля я вчера все-таки додумался, но убедил заказчика, что ему это не надо...) 

Все равно спасибо... )

Answer (score -1):

http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/ не?

Comment: Сортирует только строки, а нужно сортировать именно столбцы.

Comment: @Равнодушный если не ответят, вечером накалякую.